# Problem scraping a website with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape information from www.instacart.com using Beautifulsoup. Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('https://www.instacart.com')

content = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

print (content)
```

I am using Session because I planned to make an authorized request later. This code is working fine for all websites I have tried but not for instacart, which for some reason is simply printing "Very sorry." in my VSCode console. This is my first time trying Python and my googling for this particular error were in vain. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trick the server to think that your script  isn't a robot just use `user-agent` `header`.
Reminder that they can block your IP if you exagerate with I/O

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
header = {'user-agent': "I'm tricking you"}
response = requests.get('https://www.instacart.com', headers=header)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Several websites didn't allow web scraping, and Instacart might be one of them.

Based on the Instacart terms that you can read [here](https://www.instacart.com/terms),

> ... ... You may only access the Services through the interfaces that
> Instacart provides for that purpose (for example, **you may not “scrape”
> the Services through automated means** or “frame” any part of the
> Services) ... ...